# Como sacar el userId de la variable de un arreglo dentro de la variable de sesión en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero extraer el nombre del arreglo que meti en la variable de sesión para mostrarlo con un texto algo asi como "bienvenido".$usuario

```
<?php

require_once('../php/config.php');

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query="SELECT *FROM user WHERE UserName='$usuario' and Password='$password'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$profile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($filas >0)
{   
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $profile;
    header("location:cpanel.php");
}

else
{
    echo"Usuario o contraseña incorrectos!";
    echo '<br><a href="../index.php">Volver</a>';
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: simplemente llámala así `$_SESSION['usuario']` aunque podrías poner el isset primero para verificar si está

Comment: Gracias hermano, lo que hice fue crear un mysqli_fetch_assoc(); para que me guardara todos los datos del perfil en la variable de sesión, también necesitaba delimitarle la zona al usuario hehe, muchas gracias!

Comment: Si resolviste tu duda sería bueno que pusieras tu solución como respuesta y la marcaras por buena, por si alguien tiene el mismo problema que tú, le pueda ser útil